# Turkmenistan visa in Uzbekistan?

Tags: visas, new-zealand-citizens, uzbekistan, turkmenistan

I'll be passing through Uzbekistan shortly, and am considering getting a Turkmenistan visa for a quick visit into there.  What locations can I get this at, and any idea how long it will take to achieve?  I'm on a New Zealand passport.

Comment: Did you end up going? Asking for the purposes of https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3907/have-we-visited-all-the-countries-territories-as-a-community

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get your visa at any Turkmen consulate in the world. Currently there is only one Embassy in Uzbekistan:

```
 - Uzbekistan, Tashkent
 - Telephone: +998 (71) 1205278,9
 - Fax: +998 (71) 1205281
 - Address: 1 Bol. Mirabadskaya 10 700090 Tashkent
```

For stays of up to 10 days you can (possibly - see edit) get your visa on arrival at the Ashgabat airport.

You can expect processing to take between 1-5 working days. If I were you I'd ring the consulate in Uzbekistan and check with them what their requirements are. Should be no problems for a New Zealander (unless you're a journalist). Note that you need to tell them upfront if you're planning on bringing in a vehicle, and you also need a permit to visit the nature reserves/border zones. You'll also need a letter of invitation or a letter of recommendation from your own embassy.

e: to provide sources/links for verification:

- List of [Turkmen Embassies](http://www.turkmenistanembassy.org/turkmen/info/Emb-Consulates.html) abroad.
- [Detailed](http://www.hansrossel.com/english/turkmenistanVISA.html) info including areas for which you need extra permits.
- [This page](http://www.stantours.com/tm_mn_vis_det.html#cons) seems to indicate that if you want to pick up the visa at the airport you need to arrange it in advance.